# Laravel: query is only fetching one related id

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Im trying to get all id's that are related to a specific list but my query is only returning the first related id in the table and not the others.

**Tables**

```
List      | id | person_id | name      | description
          | 1  | 10        | Test List | null

List_Ref  | id | list_id   | data_id 
          | 1  | 1         | 100
          | 2  | 1         | 101
```

**Query**

```
$lists = DB::table('List')
   ->leftJoin('List_Ref', 'List_Ref.list.id', '=', 'List.id')
   ->select('List.id', 'List.name', 'List_Ref.data_id')
   ->where('person_id', Auth::user()->person_id)
   ->groupBy('List.id')
   ->orderBy('List.id')
   ->get();
```

**Result** (Laravel Die and Dump)

```
#items: array:1 [
  0 => {
    "id"      : 1
    "name"    : "Test List"
    "data_id" " 100
  }
]
```

I would like to produce a result like the following

```
#items: array:1 [
  0 => {
    "id"      : 1
    "name"    : "Test List"
    "data_id" => {
      "id" : 100
      "id" : 101
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Are you trying replace get() -> all()

Comment: you will get all results you need, if you remove group by.

Comment: @MubasharAbbas i need all 'data_id' grouped to one list

Comment: For identical list_id, group_by would pick only one data and then sort in ascending order.

Comment: @SanzeebAryal Thank you i didnt know that

Comment: @WesMurray then you will need to use some aggregate function like `GROUP_CONCAT()` to concat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get available grouped items don't use group by while building your query.

Do like this:

```
$lists = DB::table('List')
   ->leftJoin('List_Ref', 'List_Ref.list.id', '=', 'List.id')
   ->select('List.id', 'List.name', 'List_Ref.data_id')
   ->where('person_id', Auth::user()->person_id)
   ->get();

$lists->groupBy('List.id')->orderBy('List.id');
```

Use laravel collection's groupBy and orderBy method to get the grouped items. Hope it helps you!

Comment: even better thank you so much. this worked 100% without having to change all of the code. well done

Answer (score 0):

I dont know laravel but you are doing a left join from "List" to "List_Ref".
So every entry in Talbe List will be matched with ONE entry of List_Ref.

Try Full join.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `groupBy('List.id')` It will group the data on the basis of id of List table & always return only single data.

Comment: Thank you. i now understand that. when i remove 'groupBy()' it shows me 2 array items with the id's which is great. but i would like to group all the ID's related to a list. in 1 array

Comment: I am not laravel person, but for that case query should be : select group_concat(List_Ref.id) ids, blah...blah... group by List.id

Comment: You can use `whereRaw` to achieve something like the above. `->whereRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(List_Red.id)')`

Comment: the group_concat along with groupBy('list.id') worked. i will mark this post as an answer. according to @DipanwitaKundu